# Problem with Wedderburn Theorem proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

This is a Wedderburn Theorem proof in **Frank W. Anderson,  Kent R. Fuller: Rings and Categories of Modules**

[image]

Please explain that: "Therefore $_RR$ has a composition series of length $n$". Exercise (11.5)

[image]

Comment: For the first one: Every ring is a module over itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Maybe you didn't remember that $T^{(n)}$ is notation for $\oplus_{i=1}^{n}T$?)

Take the statement $_RR\cong T^{(n)}$ and look at that exercise. Since the sum is direct, the last line of (1) says that $c(_RR)=\sum_{i=1}^n c(_RT)$. But the composition length of $_RT$ is $1$, therefore $_RR$ has composition length $n$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But u can prove (1) to use it?

Comment: @Rachel I *can*... if you want a solution for *that* question you might consider asking another question :) It's a bit too much for a comment, and not really relevant to the original question here.